# tasm not run predefined data in variable

Tags: assembly, emulation, x86-16, tasm

I am assigning some value in a variable

```
ar db 107,106,105,104,103,102,101,100,99,98
```

and also not run string

```
msg db "this is not printed by tasm ","$"
```

but this is run on emu8086 emulator 
The actual code

### The Bubble Sort

```
data segment
ar db 107,106,105,104,103,102,101,100,99,98
ends


code segment
 start:
assume cs:code,ds:data
mov ax, data
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax



mov cl,00h
   lb1:
mov ch,09h
sub ch,cl
mov si,0
lb2:
    mov dl,ar[si]
    mov dh,ar[si+1]
    cmp dl,dh
    jle finish
    mov ar[si],dh
    mov ar[si+1],dl
finish:
    inc si
    dec ch
    cmp ch,00
    jg lb2
inc cl
cmp cl,09h
jl lb1


mov cx,10
mov si,0
  lb3:
mov dl,ar[si]
mov ah,02h
int 21h

inc si
loop lb3

mov ax, 4c00h 
int 21h    
ends

end start
```

---

then what's the problem I can't identify this
thanks for your support
please I need the result don't be lazy

Comment: You need to post the rest of the code

Comment: How about sharing actual symptoms?

Comment: hello, please anyone find out what is the problem when I am using this code in TASM ( that is arise error)

Answer (score 0):

.model small
.stack
.data
.code
org   5000h

```
buff db 256 dup(?)
```

start:
    mov   ah, 3fh           ; reading a string from standard input
    xor   bx, bx
    mov   dx, offset buff
    mov   cx, size buff
    int   21h
    jnc   okay
    ret

okay:
    mov   bx, offset buff
    sub   al, 2             ; ignore the CRLF
    push  ax
    cmp   al, 2             ; two or more chars ?
    jb    sorted

```
add   ax, bx
dec   ax
mov   cx, ax            ; cx - ptr. to the last element
inc   bx                ; starting with the second element
```

for1:
    mov   si, cx            ; the inner loop always starts from the last element
    mov   dl, 1             ; dl is used as the "sorted" flag

for2:
    mov   ax, [si - 1]      ; get two chars
    cmp   al, ah            ; are they in order ?
    jbe   cool
    xor   dl, dl            ; no, then reset the "sorted" flag
    mov   [si - 1], ah      ; ... and exchange the values
    mov   [si], al

cool:
    dec   si                ; ok, the inner loop continues until si < bx
    cmp   si, bx
    jae   for2

```
test  dl, dl            ; some exchanges occured ?
jne   sorted            ; nope - then the array is sorted

inc   bx                ; the outer loop continues till
cmp   bx, cx            ; bx goes past the last element in array ...
jbe   for1
```

sorted:
    pop   cx                ; write the result at the standard output
    xor   bx, bx
    mov   ah, 40h
    inc   bx
    mov   dx, offset buff
    int   21h

```
ret
```

end start